# Get access list of a user on Win 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, users

I would like to find all unused accounts of the active directory, so I need to see the last access to the domain. I looked into the user properties but I did not find anything. Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up your `AD Users & Computers`. Go to `Saved Queries`. Rightclick > `New` > `Query`.
Give it an easy to remember name. Click on `Define Query`. Find > `Custom Search` > `Advanced`.

Paste this into the box:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(lastLogonTimeStamp<=128147796000000000))
```

Press `OK` twice. Voila, you now have the accounts that have not logged on since Feb. 1, 2007.

[image]

If you want to change the date, change the number in the qry above. You can use [this tool for the conversion](http://www.4webhelp.net/us/timestamp.php). [Alternative here](http://unixtimetool.com/)

Comment: It is needed the Win 2003 domain level, before 2003 compatibility this doesn't work.

Comment: This works in all domains with a functional level 2003 or higher. If you are running anything below 2003 FL, you should consider upgrading ASAP.

Comment: I know i should, but I have to get informations about this upgrade to understand what it will change.

Comment: @Tobia: You can use ADSI edit to check manually, or write your own LDAP script to get the information from an earlier domain FL.  The attribute is called lastLogonTimeStamp ... and good luck with that.  Might wanna elevate the domain first, then worry about querying AD attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the built-in tools like Active Directory Users, and check for additional columns on your Domain Controller.

Also you can connect to your domain controller with LDAP Administrator or similar tool, so you can see perfectly all the smallest details of the LDAP DB, but some is binary data, so to change anything it's really much better to use Windows Domain Controller tools.

Comment: I did not found anything on additional columns...